# Can't create columns with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to learn Bootstrap. I have now i problem with the Grid-System. I can't create columns in rows.

This sample code should work but i didn't get it to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>

        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    ID
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    Name
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    E-Mail
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    100001
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    Joe
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    <replacedEmail@nowhere.com>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    100
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    Christine
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    <replacedEmail@nowhere.com>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the displayed result on my Browser:

![An image should be here, but it contains personal e-mail addresses][1]

The result should be something like a table.

Whats wrong with my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're using 2.x CSS class names (ie; `span*`) with Bootstrap 3. 
Check out this list of the changes from 2.x to 3: http://bootply.com/migrate-to-bootstrap-3

Using the upgrade tool at: http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/, I changed your markup to...

```
<div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            ID
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            Name
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            E-Mail
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            100001
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            Joe
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            MamiePVillalobos@teleworm.us
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            100
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            Christine
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            ChristineJWilliams@dayrep.com
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo on Bootply: http://bootply.com/73851

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Bootstrap js and Bootstrap CSS to view as table. Add the following lines the header part of your code.

```
<script src="http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and its work. But its work without the js too. I only add <link href="http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> and the table is visible now.  But i don't understand why its not working with <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">.. The bootstrap.css is in the css folder and tthe bootstrap tabs are displayed correct but the columns not.. Do you know why? ..

Comment: zennon, I used http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css and it worked fine. Might be css source file, the one you have in css folder, have some issue. You can open the link what I have given in a tab and do "Save As" the file and use that file. It should work now. Thanks :)

Comment: yes.. i have had the older version of bootstrap in my js folder. That was the problem. Thank you prava!